# What version of Puppy Linux should I use if I have a 2gb RAM? Do I need the PAE version?

Tags: puppy-linux

I want to try out Puppy Linux to run on my USB. What version should I use? Do I need to use the PAE version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* to, but you should.  Although the main purpose of [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) is to allow more than 4GB of physical RAM, it also enables the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit), which is a valuable security feature.

Unless your computer is extremely old and doesn't support PAE, you should use the PAE kernel.  (Or a 64-bit kernel, if your computer supports that.)